# Modal usage: would, could

Tags: word-choice, modal-verbs

In this sentence would it be better to use 'would' or 'could?' What's the difference?

> I **[would/could]** go to the party, but I wasn't invited.

Comment: All sorts of "mixed tenses" are tolerated in (particularly, *spoken, colloquial*) English. But most likely you'd want *would/could have gone* in this context, because it's a better fit with ***wasn't** invited*.

Comment: Actually, @FumbleFingers- Consider: Margot: "I'm going to Kate's party tonight. Are you."  "No, I would go, but I wasn't invited."

Comment: What about "I could go to the party, but I wasn't invited," as in "Even though I wasn't invited, I could still go?"

Anyway, I think between choster's answer and the comments, we've got some great answers. I'll mark his answer as answering the question. Thanks for the help and comments!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many different uses of *would* and *could*, and depending on the context, using *could* may or may not make sense here.

---

I think *would* here would take the sense of

> **[would (*willing*)](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/would_5)** - used to talk about what someone was willing to do or what something was able to do

Thus, to say

> I would go to the party, but I wasn't invited.

expresses that you would like to go to the party— but will not because you were not invited.

But you could use *could* here in the sense of

> **[could (*possibility*)](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/could_4)** - used to express possibility, especially slight or uncertain possibility

Suppose, for example, I am weighing my options for what to do on the weekend.

> We could go on a picnic, but it might rain. I could go hiking, but my knee might act up again. I could go to the party, but I wasn't invited.

You acknowledge the *possibility* of those activities, but you do not necessarily *desire* to do so, and think it unlikely you will, because you anticipate some problems.

Comment: Yes, but another feasible implication of using *could* here is in the sense of *having the capability/would be able to*. For example, *"I have the requisite jacket and tie, so I **could** go to the party if I were invited."* Which is slightly different to *"Perhaps I **could** go to the party - I haven't made my mind up yet."*

Comment: @FumbleFingers Fair enough. I eliminated several other hypothetical examples I was going to include, as the answer was getting incredibly unwieldy.